# Connection to Redshift database through Ruby on Rails, blazer hanging and failing

Tags: ruby, amazon-redshift, ruby-on-rails-6, blazer

In a Ruby on Rails 6 project, I am using the [blazer gem](https://github.com/ankane/blazer#amazon-redshift) and whenever I add an AWS redshift database, the connection keeps hanging and loading for a long time, and then fails

```bash
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on host "redshift-cluster-x.xxxxxxx.us-east-x.redshift.amazonaws.com" (34.xx.30.xxx) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5439?
```

Connection

```rb
# data_source.settings["url"] = redshift://username:password@redshift-cluster-1.xxxxx.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/dev
establish_connection(data_source.settings["url"])
```

. I have the [activerecord6-redshift-adpater](https://github.com/kwent/activerecord6-redshift-adapter) gem installed

[image]

Ensured public access
[image]

Also, the VPC routes

[image]